# When can I change a partial differentiation to a normal differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**When can I change a partial differentiation to a normal differentiation? What I mean is, when can I change $ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ to $\frac{d}{dt}$?**

*Example:*

In the  Boltzmann equation, I have seen the LHS of the equation written as :

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f_s (p,t) - Hp \frac{\partial}{\partial p}f_s (p,t)= ....$$

and I have been told to get it to the form:

$$\frac{d}{dt} f_s (p,t) - Hp \frac{\partial}{\partial p}f_s (p,t)= ....$$

Comment: They aren't equivalent unless the function considered has one variable.

Comment: A single variable?

Comment: Yes as in $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}x}(x)$$